# like button does no pick the correct image

Tags: php, facebook, button, facebook-like, thumbnails

hello how are you this is the first question for me, i have searched on every thing has a related with my issue here  but it does not solve my problem.

my problem  with Facebook like button it does not pick the right image that i have assigned to my topic ,it picks random images but when i enter the url for my topic on Facebook debugger my image that i have assign will display successfully  .

these are my all meta tags:

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="helloworl.net" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="100005448308575" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="153624041471824"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $facebook_title ; ?>" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $actual_link ;  ?>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="

<?php
if($row->con_image){
echo $row->con_image;
}else{
echo "http://www.einelhelweh.net/ein.jpg";
}

?>

" />


<meta property="og:site_name" content="helloworld.net" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="100005448308575" />

<meta property="og:description"
          content="Hello world"/>
```

when i right click on the page that contains my topic and choose "view page resource my " my specific image will appear correctly.

dimension of my image that i have assisted to Facebook like button  thumbnail is true

also i have used php header to clear the cache but same thigs

```
$gmt_mtime = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() ) . ' GMT';
header("Last-Modified: " . $gmt_mtime );
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1995 12:12:12 GMT">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
```

also i have clear the redirect that i have created to my old website folder but same thing

i have searched not here just but on facebook and other sites but no hope

i am still suffering from this problem since 1 years ago and i have searched on Google but no hope

please please please i need help i do not want to exit from here without a solution.

thanks's for all guys.and forgive me

Comment: It may not like all the line breaks in the og:image tag. Check https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: when i enter the url for my topic on Facebook debugger my image that i have assign will display successfully.i have mentioned that above

Comment: Give us an example URL to try, then.

Comment: certainly try this : http://www.einelhelweh.net/shownews.php?full=news&id_topic=2729

Comment: please guys where are the experts here, is it mean no solution for my problem. i am still waiting a solution. please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your og:image tag looks like this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="

http://www.einelhelweh.net/ein.jpg
" />
```

I'd remove all the whitespace, for starters. That said, Facebook appears to be picking it up OK. Here's an example when I try to post to my wall:

[image]

Comment: i think facebook has tarted to pick the right image after i make as you menthion :<meta property="og:image" content="<?php if($row->con_image){echo $row->con_image;}else{echo "http://www.einelhelweh.net/ein.jpg";}?>"/>

Comment: i think Facebook has started to pick the right image if so i will mark accepted answer.just wait me to tell you if my problem has been solved

Comment: i noticed that some images that i have specified is accepted and some images does not but when i put the link in facebook debugger it will tell  :Provided og:image is not big enough. Please use an image that's at least 200x200 and preferably 1500x1500. (Maximum image size is 5MB.) Image 'http://www.einelhelweh.net/upload/images/867182826.jpeg' will be used instead.and after that the image will appear."but i want to say that images that i have specified is larger than 200 200 ? \

Comment: although my problem does not solved completely but you answer is loved a part of my problem so that i will consider your answer is solved my problem thank you ceejayoz